# CURL is failed in sending the parameters to the Server

Tags: php, post, cookies, curl

I am going to send a Log in request to the server by using CURL in my PHP code. This request is POST and I wrote following code,

```
    if (strpos($header, 'POST') !== false){
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => 1, 
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'proxy',
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postParameters,
            CURLOPT_COOKIE => $postCoockies
         ));
        $respond = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl); }
```

and if I want to say what my variables are here:

```
$url is the exact String after POST and before HTTP/1.1.
```

when I want to send the GET request also, I am using this part as my urs which would be contained all parameters in my query String.

```
$postParameters is the exact String that exist in POST body.
```

(That's a String, not an associative array)

```
$postCoockies in the exact String after Cookie: in my request header.
```

(again, that's not an associative array)

My problem is:

When I send this request, server sends me back a response to only the URL I am passing. Which is to load the login page again! it seems that the server is not receiving my parameters!
Also, when I used GET request for login (I have access to the source code of website), and sent the whole URL and parameters inside the $url, the same thing happened.

Am I wrong somewhere in sending my request?
Should I consider something else here?

Comment: Actually, I just got that my problem is not with this POST request. After this POST I am redirected to the first URL with a new cookie. This request is a GET request. I am sure that I am sending the new cookie to the server! But server cannot distinguish me as a prior client and will load the page for me by setting another cookie for me... How can I pass this problem here?

Comment: I got the answer... I needed to use CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE instead of CURLOPT_COOKIE. Thanks anyway! I'm not gonna remove this post, maybe it can help someone else as well.